# setInterval works then hangs browser javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval, infinite-loop

I'm wanting to animate an element using `setInterval`. I've put my code into an object with 2 `functions` one to initialize and one to animate using `setInterval`. When I try to run the code the animation works once then causes the browser to hang. The only thing I can think of is an infinite loop being created somewhere however I can't see anywhere in my code that would cause this.

What is causing the browser to crash, how can this be overcome ?

```
<div id='box' style='position:absolute;height:100px;width:100px;background-color:#44e'>box</div>
<script>
var box = {
init : function(elemId) {
    box.elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
box.timer = setInterval;
    box.tick = 0;

    box.animate();
},
animate: function() {
    if(box.tick < 100) {
        box.elem.style.top = box.tick +'px';
        box.elem.style.left = box.tick +'px';
        box.tick++;
    } else {
        clearInterval(box.timer);
    }
    var timer = setInterval(box.animate, 50)
}
}
box.init('box');
</script>
```

Comment: What do you think `box.timer = setInterval;` does?

Comment: var timer = setInterval(box.animate, 50) is called every 50 milliseconds;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` sets up a function that will be called **repeatedly** by the browser until you cancel the interval timer. Your code isn't doing that, because the only call to `clearInterval` is using `box.timer`, which is never set to a timer handle (the return value from `setInterval`). So you end up scheduling thousands of calls (a new series every time `animate` is called) and bringing the browser to its kneeds.

At the very least, this:

```
var timer = setInterval(box.animate, 50)
```

should probably be:

```
box.timer = setInterval(box.animate, 50);
```

Or you may want `setTimeout` (which schedules only **one** call back).